# How to change line width in figure legend in julia Plots?

Tags: julia, plots.jl

```
using Plots
plot(1:1:5, 1:1:5, linewidth=1)
plot!(1:1:5, 1:2:10, linewidth=5)
```

Is it possible to make the legend line width match the line width in the plot? I couldn't find anything in the [documentation](http://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/attributes/) unfortunately.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Try this out:

```
using Plots
plot(1:1:5, 1:1:5, linewidth=1)
plot!(1:1:5, 1:2:10, linewidth=5, thickness_scaling = 1)
```

The resulting output would be the following:
[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for, but sadly does not work for me with Julia v1.4.2 and Plots v1.4.3. What do you use? Also tried changing the thickness_scaling = 1 to other values.

Comment: @mihapriimek, I'm on Julia 1.4.2 and I'm using the version v1.0.14 of Plots

Comment: Does not work on Julia 1.6 and StatsPlots v0.14.26

Comment: Use CairoMakie.jl. The legend will use the same linewidth from the `lines` plot